# how to simplify -1 to shared power (produced by Solve)

Tags: equation-solving

I want a real solution to look real.  But this solution does not:

```
Clear[c1, c2, c3, p1, a, u]
eqns = {p == c1^(-1 + a) c2^(1 - a) a c3, 1 == c1^a c2^-a (1 - a) c3, 
  u == c1^a c2^(1 - a)}
assumptions = p > 0 && 1 > a > 0
(* Solve works, but ... *)
Solve[eqns, {c1, c2, c3}]  (* specifying domain is worse *)
Simplify[%, Assumptions -> assumptions] (* FullSimplify does not help *)
```

produces

```
{{c1 -> -E^(-I a π) (((-1 + a) p)/a)^(-1 + a) u, 
  c2 -> ((-1 + 1/a) p)^a u, c3 -> -(((-1 + 1/a) p)^a/(-1 + a))}}
```

This is "correct", but in the first solution (for c1) has that ugly `(-1)^a` (which can be seen after applying Euler's identity) would should be simplified away.  Can I somehow force Mma to do that simplification?

Comment: where do you see `(-1)^a` ?

Comment: @george2079  Apply Euler's identity to `E^(-I a π)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear[c1, c2, c3, p1, a, u];

eqns = {p == c1^(-1 + a) c2^(1 - a) a c3, 1 == c1^a c2^-a (1 - a) c3, 
   u == c1^a c2^(1 - a)};

assumptions = p > 0 && 1 > a > 0;

soln = Assuming[assumptions,
  Solve[eqns, {c1, c2, c3}][[1]] // ExpToTrig // FullSimplify]
```

[image]

```
eqns /. soln // Simplify[#, assumptions] &
```

> {True, True, True}

Comment: @BobHanon  Nice.  `ExpToTrig` is new to me.  Thanks!